# Regex to allow only these [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to find a way with regex to verify a string I am getting as a parameter

this has to be one word that consists only of these characters: [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

what I've tried

```
   var pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9~\-_.]\S{42,128}$";
   if (!Regex.IsMatch(authorizationRequest.CodeChallenge, pattern))
   {
        return new PkceResponse
        {
             IsValid = false,
             Error = OIDCErrorCodes.InvalidRequest,
             ErrorDescription = "Code Challenge contains invalid characters",
             ParameterName = "code_challenge"
        };
   }
```

but my tests fail with this input:
`longenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughAABSC__-......~~~.~-!`
what did I miss?

Comment: @John  restrict spaces, to my understanding

Comment: i reckon you missed the `\S`, which matches any non-whitespace-character, including that `!` at the end.

Comment: I ran your code on my system, it works and the pattern matches. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is as follows:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9~\-_.]\S{42,128}$
```

Let's break it down into its components:

- `^` - Matches the beginning of the input.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9~\-_.]` - Match a single character a-z A-Z 0-9 ~ - _ or .
- `\S` - Matches any character except a white-space character.
- `{42,128}` - Matches previous element at least 42 times and at most 128 times. In this case, the previous element is `\S`.
- `$` - Matches the end of the input, or the point before a final \n at the end of the input.

[Source for most definitions](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

So as we can see your regular expression currently does the following:

It first matches a single character a-z A-Z 0-9 ~ - _ or . at the start of the string. It then matches any non-whitespace character 42-128 times, and expects the end of the input to follow immediately afterwards. This means that we expect a string with a total length of 43-129 characters.

As your question states, you only want to match those specific characters, so your expression should actually be this (I've removed the `\S`):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9~\-_.]{42,128}$
```

As for your specific input:

> longenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughlongenoughAABSC__-......~~~.~-!

It appears that you have included an exclamation mark (`!`) at the end of your input, which of course doesn't match your constraint.

Comment: My 1st thought was (I got tricked again) to use the shorthand `\w` for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but in .NET this will match characters outside the ASCII-pallet. To force the right behaviour we can include the [ECMAScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ecmascript-matching-behavior) option to the options parameter. That would then allow for `^[\w~.-]{42,128}$`, but I guess it's better to be more descriptive in .NET expressions in general.